# How to convert binary to uuid

Tags: java, binary, uuid, mongodb-compass

I have a question about the uuids representation in mongoDb Compass. All the uuids are converted into the binaries and it is hard to find them.

For now I just want to find two algorithms for converting

`87c8bc80-4fce-11e9-8647-1563bd873d93`

into

`6RHOT4C8yIeTPYe9YxVHhg==`

and vice versa.

All the algorithms that I have already found either don't work for the binaries with the length shorter than 32 or suit only for the binaries with the subtype 0X04 (and this is definitely not the one).

Could you help me?

Comment: base64 and a bit of shuffling

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger is it possible to decode somehow?

Comment: use BASE64 and correct order of bytes. e.g. linux command `echo "6RHOT4C8yIeTPYe9YxVHhg==" | base64 -d | od -t x8` returns `87c8bc804fce11e9 86471563bd873d93` - now this must be converted to java. Check classes [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) and [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html)